# jquery help (using backbone $.el in knockout)

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, knockout.js

hi I am trying to transfer this code from backbone to knockout. i am guessing its more of a jQuery question as backbone uses $el as a helper?

the code in backbone is

```
//this.el is the root element of Backbone.View. By default, it is a div.    
//$el is cached jQuery object for the view's element.
//append the compiled template into view div container

  this.$el.append(***some html***);
```

so console.log (this.$el) returns an object

i have tried

```
console.log($(** some html **))
```

but this just return the name of the first dive and not the object...

Answer (score 0):

`var el` in javascript usually refers to whichever element you're trying to get / set something to.

for instance, in jQuery something common would be:

`$('this')`

or in Javascript it could be:

`getElementById('your element e.g: my-awesome-id')`

For this situation I think it'd actually be read as:

`this.('div').append('<span>we append something here</span>')`

instead of `console.log($(** some html **))` try using `console.log(this.$el)`

I hope this helps you on your way, Cheers!